# Assembly to C matrix assitance

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm really confused by my homework assignment. We are given C code and then assembly which are listed below. This is x86 assembly. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I've made an attempt to solve it based on what I'm understanding.

C code:

```
void transpose(Marray_t A) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
           int t = A[i][j];
           A[i][j] = A[j][i];
           A[j][i] = t;
        }
}
```

Assembly code for ONLY inner loop:

```
1 .L3:
2 movl (%ebx), %eax     //is this getting the mem location of %ebx and setting to %eax?
3 movl (%esi,%ecx,4), %edx  //ecx * 4 + esi into edx
4 movl %eax, (%esi,%ecx,4)  //
5 addl $1, %ecx             //add 1 to ecx
6 movl %edx, (%ebx)         //move edx to mem location of ebx???
7 addl $52, %ebx            //I think this is M but I could be wrong
8 cmpl %edi, %ecx           //compare edi & ecx
9 jl .L3
```

here is what I have to answer:

A. What is the value of M? ...I think this is 52...?

B. What registers hold program values i and j? ... I think edx and eax?

C. Write a C code version of transpose that makes use of the optimizations
that occur in this loop. Use the parameter M in your code rather than numeric
constants.

Attempt at (C):

```
void tranpose(Marray_t A) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int *row = &A[i][0];
            int *col = &A[0][j];

            int value = (*row * 4) + *col;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to review (and accept my answer if appropriate) for your other question on assembly -> C before going any further?

Comment: That's what I was confused about I didn't know if we could determine M from what was given. I copied this straight from the text book so I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 .L3:
2 movl (%ebx), %eax         // eax := read memory word at ebx
3 movl (%esi,%ecx,4), %edx  // edx := read memory word at esi + 4*ecx
4 movl %eax, (%esi,%ecx,4)  // store eax into that location
5 addl $1, %ecx             // add 1 to ecx
6 movl %edx, (%ebx)         // store edx into memory at ebx
7 addl $52, %ebx            // add 52 to ebx
8 cmpl %edi, %ecx           // compare edi & ecx
9 jl .L3
```

So in this code. `%ebx` is the the address of `A[j][i]`, `%esi` is the address of `A[i]` and `%ecx` is j.  52 is `sizeof(A[j])`, so M is probably 13 (as the array element size is 4)

Comment: Ok that makes since I'm really struggling with converting to C now. I posted the code I have so far but I still need help.